# add a contact to BBM from my BB 10 cascades app

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, bb-messenger

I am new to BB 10 cascades and Black berry Platform provided features. I would like to add a contact say 3BDAEE2D to BBM Contacts from my BB 10 Cascades Application. How to do it Programatically? please suggest me a way so that I can Quickly solve it...

Thanks!!!

Hi MSohm,

your post  is worked for me ,but small problem.

Please find this!!!

```
InvokeActionItem {
                    id:supportBBM          
                    title: qsTr("Support") + Retranslate.onLanguageChanged
                    ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.InOverflow

                    imageSource: "asset:///images/support_icon.png"
                    query {
                        invokeActionId: "bb.action.INVITEBBM"
                        uri: "pin:2ADAEE2F"
                    }
                }
```

I am using this. but when I switch language option from English to Arabic in my app, Its is displaying Arabic language very first time and It is never changing again even when I change my language option from Arabic to English next time.

when I close the app and open again then it is showing corresponding language which was selected previously.

I want to do it,but didn't get how to do that...

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by invoking BBM using Invite to BBM.  Here is an example of how to do it in QML.

```
InvokeActionItem {
title: "Invite to BBM"
query {
    invokeActionId: "bb.action.INVITEBBM"
    uri: "pin:3BDAEE2D"
}
```

Documentation on this can be found here:  https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/invocation/bbm.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!! I have couple of questions 1.Do I need to register with BBM to achieve this?  2. I am testing this on simulator and successfully moving to  BBM and getting "setup BBM now to chat and share with your blackberry contacts in real time".Can the same work on Device?

Answer (score 0):

I try this and is working ,

Thanks !!!

```
action :[
 ActionItem {
                    title: qsTr("Support") + Retranslate.onLanguageChanged
                    ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.InOverflow

                    imageSource: "asset:///images/support_icon.png"

                    onTriggered: {
                        supportBBM.trigger("bb.action.INVITEBBM")
                    }
                }
  ]
 attachedObjects: [
 Invocation {
            id: supportBBM
            query {
                invokeActionId: "bb.action.INVITEBBM"
                uri: "pin:2ADAEE2F"
            }
 ]
```